# JQuery change the text to heading

Tags: jquery, css, text, formatting

I have a named     `<form>`     (no id) with some text and input elements. I need to change the format of the text to a heading style.

```
<form name="myform">
    <br/>
    Text Snippet #1<br/>
    <input type="text"><br/>
    <br>Text Snippet #2</br><br/>
    <input type="text">`<br/>
</form>`<br/>
```

So in the example above, the Text Snippets #1 & 2 should be decorated with 
`<h1>Text Snippet #1</h1>`
 and `<br><h1>Text Snippet #2</h1></br>` respectively.

Comment: You don't need a closing <br> tag.

Comment: I don't see a question here, can you not just edit the source?

Answer (score 0):

You could `.filter()` and `.wrap()` them:

```
$('form[name=myform]').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
}).wrap('<h1/>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AWJs4/

Comment: That worked, for the sake of performance is it safe to omit the $.trim(this.nodeValue).length check?

Comment: @PavanLulla Well removing that part doesn't change the performance too much, it just trims the value of the matching `textNode`s, if you omit it, you will have empty heading elements.